# how to obtain the number of files in tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: tensorflow, keras

how to obtain the number of files in tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory?

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)
```

Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.

Comment: It says it found `3670` files. 2936 will be used for training (`3670 - 0.2 * 3670`). What is it you are after exactly?

Comment: Hey buddy how did you installed the function? Can you please show the imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
import numpy as np

len(np.concatenate([i for x, i in train_ds], axis=0))
```

this gives you the number of files, in this case 2936.

Comment: Hi @Stat Tistician, thanks for your answer, this takes very long to calculate, I had to stopp, do you know any shorter way btw?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *index_directory* helper function:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import dataset_utils
file_paths, _, _ = dataset_utils.index_directory(data_dir, 'inferred', ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png'))
print('Total files:', len(file_paths))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case this will work:

```
len(train_ds.file_paths)
```

A tip to find metadata in objects is to set a breakpoint and run debugger. Once the object is initiazied you can inspect what it is build up of.

For this case you can easily find that you `train_ds` contains a field named `file_paths`. Inspecting it further you see that it is just a normal list which we easily can extract the length from.